# add a button to activeadmin column that updates resource attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have an index in activeadmin. Something like:

```
index do
 selectable_column
 column "Date"
 column "Type"
 ..
 column "mark"
end
```

I require last column to have a button, clicking which will update an attribute of the resource. Some thing link

```
 column "mark" do |resource|
   # a button 
   # on click: resource.update_attributes :marked => True
 end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If that resource provides a form to perform updates then the `link_to` method
can build a remote request to update various attributes on click:

```
index do
  column "Mark" do |resource|
    link_to("Mark",
      admin_resource_path(resource, resource: { marked: true }),
      remote: true, method: :patch
    )
  end
end
```

The key pieces are `remote: true` to make a remote request and `method: patch`
to issue an update to the resource.

Note that the references to `admin_resource_path` and `resource` must be updated
for the actual resource in use. An example for a `Post` resource:

```
index do
  column "Actions" do |post|
    link_to("Touch",
      admin_post_path(post, post: { updated_at: Time.now }),
      remote: true, method: :patch
    )
  end
end
```